# Getting Eclipse to warn about performance bugs

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does Eclipse have any plugin that solve performance bugs like IntelliJ?

Example for performance bug:

```
int [] a,b;
b=f();
a=new int[b.length];
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
{
    a[i]=b[i];
}
```

IntelliJ advice to use in System.CopyArray function.

Comment: Literally, no.  Are they "as good as" IntelliJ?  Try them and judge for yourself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Eclipse, use the [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/integrations.html#eclipse), [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html) and [CheckStyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) plugins.

I've never used IntelliJ IDEA for any extended amount of time, so I can't promise which features you will find the same or different. Eclipse, IDEA and Netbeans have many similarities but the details are often vastly different.

PMD, for example, has the warning `AvoidArrayLoops` which should flag the code above.

If you're missing something, all these tools support custom extensions.

But Eclipse isn't IntelliJ IDEA.

The advantage of these plugins is that they are available for all IDEs, so you can configure them once and you'll see the same warnings everywhere.

Comment: +1 - (Nitpick ... it is the PMD/FindBugs/CheckStyle *tools* that are IDE independent.  The respective plugins for the different IDEs are *different* for each IDE.  They have to be, because they talk to different menageries of IDE framework classes.)